# Using login for specified user that are able to delete their own table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my database lecturer table name persons

```
ID FirstName LastName Email
100  alex     alex     -
102  ali      ali      -
```

This is my table user_subject

```
ID  Subject
100  AAA
100  BBB
102  AAA
102  CCC
```

This is my drop_subject.php

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','password');
mysql_select_db('lecturer');

$query = 'SELECT persons.ID , persons.FirstName , user_subject.subject
FROM persons
INNER JOIN user_subject
ON persons.ID = user_subject.ID
ORDER BY persons.ID';

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Drop subject</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>ID</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Subject</strong></td>

</tr>

<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> <?php echo $row['ID']; ?> </td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> <?php echo $row['subject']; ?> </td>

</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="submit" value="Delete Checked Rows" /></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="user_subject.php?pressed=subject">Back</a></td>


</tr>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
$del_query = "DELETE FROM user_subject WHERE No IN (";
foreach($_POST['data'] as $data) {
$del_query .= "'" . (int) $data . "',";
}
$del_query .= "'')";
mysql_query($del_query) or die(mysql_error());
header("Location:" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}



mysql_close()


?>
</table>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I want to drop subject if I access as Ali I am able to drop the subject of alex.

What I want to do is like when alex access to the drop_subject.php the system only appear his own data which is ID 100 subject AAA and ID 100 subject BBB and he is able to drop his own subject only

What should I use to restrict specific user to access their own database not everyone's database?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection! Take a look at the line `$del_query .= "'" . (int) $data . "',";`. Imagine what happens if someone POSTs the following data: `123'); DROP TABLE user_subject; --`. You really should get that sorted out.

Comment: Yeah, I agree to fix the part which allows SQL injection, as a good practice. You can read more at http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: @dan: `(int)'123'); DROP TABLE ..` would result in just `123` anyways... the string's being type-cast to an int, and the sql bits would get removed.

Comment: @MarcB - you're absolutely right. I didn't notice that part. But I don't think this is an ideal way to protect against SQL injection. I don't know how php's casting works, but wouldn't some casts potentially result in NULL values that might screw up the query string?

Comment: @dan: `(int)` could potentially result in a php null, but concatenation a php null into a string results in an empty string. Since OP's got sql-level quotes around the potentially empty string, that php null would just result in `''`, which would be a valid empty string in sql

Answer (score 2):

The steps taken should be

1. Able to capture the user ID of the user currently accessing the page;
2. Filter the result with a WHERE statement together with the ID: `WHERE id = <the id of the user>`.

Comment: For example, if you pass the current access user's id via query string in the following format: drop_subject.php?user_id=100, then in your PHP code, you can first retrieve the user id by doing `$user_id = $_GET["id"]`. After that, you can use that info to filter the result by doing: `$query = 'SELECT persons.ID , persons.FirstName , user_subject.subject
FROM persons
INNER JOIN user_subject
ON persons.ID = user_subject.ID
WHERE person.ID = '.(int)$user_id.'
ORDER BY persons.ID';`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: i followed what you have stated to me and i got an error which is undefined index: ID and even i change to http://localhost/Project/testing.php?user_id=100 but if i change to $user_id = 100; i can get only 100 database. does it have any program that can use for 1 to many users thank you

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. There is typo in my code, it should be `$user_id = $_GET["user_id"]`. So, if you want to show other user's data, for example the User 102, simply update the query string to ?user_id=102. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: thank you for your reply.what i am trying to do is each user can only read their own database and when i login as alex i only wanted only alex database to appear in a multiple user database like user_subject and now i trying to figure out how to change testing.php?user_id=100 by just clicking as alex in the webpage

Comment: For a simple HTML sample, you can just have `<a href="testing.php?user_id=100">Alex</a>` and `<a href="testing.php?user_id=102">Ali</a>`. Of course, from there, you can use a for loop to generate a dynamic list of users also.